# Determine if User's online

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I determine if a user is online or not? Preferably a group of users. I was thinking everytime a user visits a page create a record in the db with `Time.now` and use AJAX to invoke periodic calls to my remote server; just to see if the time from their last noted activity was about, say, 10 minutes?

Comment: Yep, that's a pretty standard way of going about it. Go for it!

Comment: I'd recommend using memcached rather than your database - for transient data like that, it's going to be faster, and you really don't need all the DB overhead for it.

Comment: How would you use memcached here, @ChrisHeald?

Comment: @jalcine Just set a `lastonline:$userid` key with a timestamp whenever you receive a request with that user's session. Then, to check online time, just pull that key and subtract it from the current time. memcached gets/sets are extremely fast, and the overhead would be very minimal.

Comment: Clever! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) to determine if the user if online by "ping" him constantly.

Comment: This would work and it saves the potential hassle of pulling information from the database.